# Button on hover flashes a glitchy black border?

Tags: html, css

When I hover over one of these buttons it flashes a black border and then it disappears. There is no border in the code. I am also using Chrome if that causes any issues. I do not want the border here.

Here is the code:

```css
body {
  background: #5544aa;
  }

nav {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);

 border-radius: 0px;
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.1), -2px -2px .5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 }
 
nav ul {
    width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 150px;
 margin-top: 15px;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
}

li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #555555;
 border-radius: 0px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    line-height: 50px;
    display: block;
 transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}
li a:hover {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
 box-shadow: 0 8px 8px -6px #333, inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 color: #222222;
 padding: 0px 0px;
 text-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
                        }
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="index.html">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="services.html">Products</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="about.html">About</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be your `box-shadow` transitioning. To stop it, you'll need to edit your `transition` from `all` to just the CSS rules you want to transition.

Comment: I want everything to have a transition without the border.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. I needed to delete the `box-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;` in the li a { } part. Now it works just fine.